# Is there any syntax for adding new record between two records in sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, sql-insert

Please suggest how to insert new record between two records.
Id 3 of record/row is missed between id 2 and 4 in sql table.

Comment: Just insert row `3`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are unordered sets. You cannot add a record "between two records", because there is no order to the records. Even if your queries seem to return the rows in some order, it's completely arbitrary, and unless you have an explicit `order by` clause could very well change.

In other words - you should just insert the new row, and if you care about ordering by the id, always use `order by id` in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a calendar table based approach here:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (id)
SELECT t1.id
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
) t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t1.id IS NULL;
```

In practice, you might replace the inlined subquery aliased as `t1` above with a bona fide sequence table covering all `id` values which you would want to cover.